# Why would you use umask?

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am reading some source code and I found this statement at the very beginning of the main routine:

```
umask(077);
```

What could be the reason for that?

The man page (man 2 umask) states:

> umask -- set file creation mode mask
>
> This clearing allows each user to
> restrict the default access to his
> files

But is not clear to me why would anyone do that? as a shortcut ?

Comment: Are you familiar with unix file attributes, I mean do you know what means first column in command "ls -l" ? -rwx------+

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting `umask(077)` ensures that any files created by the program will only be accessible to their owner (0 in first position = all permissions potentially available) and nobody else (7 in second/third position = all permissions disallowed to group/other).

Comment: You would expect to see this setting in a program which is generating highly sensitive files that should *never* be accessed by any other user, in any situation (`ssh-keygen` is a good example).  Normal programs should respect the existing `umask()` that the user has set.

Answer (score 4):

It needs for file system security. umask contains inverted number, using as file mode for new file. For example

```
dzen@DZeN ~ $ umask
022
dzen@DZeN ~ $ touch file
dzen@DZeN ~ $ ls -la file
-rw-r--r--  1 dzen  dzen  0  6 may 14:29 file
dzen@DZeN ~ $ umask 777
dzen@DZeN ~ $ umask      
0777
dzen@DZeN ~ $ touch file1
dzen@DZeN ~ $ ls -la file1
----------  1 dzen  dzen  0  6 may 14:30 file1
```