# mq_open's oflag argument doesn't reflect actual access bits of created mqueue file

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions, mqueue

I'm calling `mq_open` on `linux 5.5.6` like so:

```c
mq_open("/testing12345", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0777, & (struct mq_attr) {0, 10, 255, 0));
```

Note that I passed `0777` as the 3rd argument.

The function succeeds and the appropriate mqueue is created, after which I mount the mqueue filesystem from my shell:

```sh
mount -t mqueue none ./mqueue_dir
```

However, stat-ing the new mqueue's node reveals `0755` as the access bits:

```sh
stat -c %a ./mqueue_dir/testing12345

0755
```

Why is that? I clearly passed the `0777` constant when calling mq_open.

---

### Reproducible example

compiled with `gcc -Wall -Werror -lrt a.c -o ./a`

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void) {
    const mqd_t descriptor = mq_open("/testing12345", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_NONBLOCK, 0777, & (struct mq_attr) {0, 10, 255, 0});
    if(descriptor == -1) {
        perror("parent: failed opening mqueue");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sleep(30u);

    mq_unlink("/testing123");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a short compilable program with `mq_open` call? It would be easier for others (like me) to test the problem ourselves then.

Comment: I've edited my question to include a program that reproduces the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ["file creation mask"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting is almost certainly set to `022`, thereby "masking" the `0777` you specified "down" to `0755`.

Per [the POSIX `umask()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html) (bolding mine):

> **NAME**
>
> umask - set and get the file mode creation mask
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <sys/stat.h>
>
> mode_t umask(mode_t cmask);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `umask()` function shall set the file mode creation mask of the
>   process to `cmask` and return the previous value of the mask. Only the
>   file permission bits of `cmask` (see `<sys/stat.h>`) are used; the
>   meaning of the other bits is implementation-defined.
>
> The file mode creation mask of the process is used to turn off
>   permission bits in the mode argument supplied during calls to the
>   following functions:
>
> - open(), openat(), creat(), mkdir(), mkdirat(), mkfifo(), and mkfifoat()
> - mknod(), mknodat()
> - mq_open()
> - sem_open()
>
> **Bit positions that are set in `cmask` are cleared in the mode of the
>   created file.**

See also [**When is umask() useful?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198623/when-is-umask-useful).

Effectively, in order to ensure the file(s) you create have a specific mode, you either have to blank out the file creation mask with `umask( 0 )`, or you have to explicitly set the exact mode you want **after** you create the file.  Since calling `umask()` affects the state of the **entire** process, it's almost always better to explicitly set the mode directly.

Comment: I didn't know that such a concept existed. Thanks!